# NGINX + ssl_verify_client: socket.io keeps connecting

Tags: ssl, nginx, socket.io

NGINX looks this way in its relevant parts:

```
listen 9443 ssl;
server_name example.com;

ssl_certificate      mycert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  mykey.key;
ssl_client_certificate myca.pem;
ssl_verify_client on;

proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8443/;
```

A socketio/node.js app look like this:

```
var restify                         = require('restify');
var server                          = restify.createServer();
var io                              = require('socket.io')    (server.server);
server.listen(8443, function () {
console.log('socket.io server listening at %s', server.url);
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log("Client connected in io.sockets.on.connection");
socket.on('testfunc', function () {
    console.log("this is testfunc");
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("Client disconnected");
});
});
```

index.html looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io('https://example.com:9443', {secure: true});
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.emit('testfunc');
    });
});
</script>
```

NGINX listens on port 9443.
Node.js on port 8443.

if this directive:
ssl_verify_client on;

is removed in nginx.conf, then no problem. After client connected it will call "testfunc" on socket.io. Works fine.

If ssl_verify_client on; is in nginx.conf the following happens:

The client seems to want to connect to socket.io continuosly. Not an infinite loop. It will try to connect every 1 second.
The emit(testunc) will never reach. Not on the client not on the server.

I dont really understand what the problem can be. The only thing I can see right now, maybe a clue, is that for every second
the url the client tries to connect to has different id, like this:

```
https://example.com:9443/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1425570178744-3&sid=A_HsCwcklo30ZlifAAAA
https://example.com:9443/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1425570179958-5&sid=gU1Nlv6asTakgE0KAAAB
https://example.com:9443/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1425570181232-11&sid=Oy6ZnW3PZbK8cojHAAAC
https://example.com:9443/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1425570182456-15&sid=-uK6YnSkYUyjPdI9AAAD
```

New findings. The problem is that the socket-request is not sending the client certificate. Also, the problem only exists in firefox (Im only interested in firefox and chrome). In chrome it works.

Doing a regular ajax-request works ONLY IF you instruct the request to send the client certificate:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://example.com:9443/test',
        type: 'GET',
        xhrFields: {'withCredentials': true}
    }).success(function (value) {
        console.log(value)
        console.log('success');
    }).error(function () {
        console.log(arguments);
        console.log('error');
    });
```

The request above works on both browsers.

Now, when doing a socket-connection it fails. It fails in Firefox. But it works on Chrome.
I've tried to find out how to write an option on socket.io that mimics the "withCredentials"-option in ajax-request.. But no luck.
Also: doing the socket conenction work in Chrome without me setting any "withCredentials"-option. it sounds like Chrome sends the client certificate by default.

Even more interesting: what protocols are the two browsers using when trying to estabilish socket connection? It seems that both do a few tests by calling socket.io with polling as transport. And then that both rely on websocket. A final work could be:
Both firefox and chrome use websocket to connect to server. However, when in chrome, the certificate is sent by default(?) while in firefox it isn't.

Comment: "Quite" good news. I found a workaround. And the cause of the problem. When firefox only use (or prioritized) polling as tranport, then it fails. My translation would be "it doesnt send certificate when polling in firefox". However, in Chrome it works. So having all the transports but excluding polling makes it work in both browsers.

Comment: If I go into socket.io.js and when xmlhttprequest is set up I add "withCredentials" it still doesnt work (if polling). Im afraid its about browser's security.